# Flutter: conditionals in initializer

Tags: dart, flutter

In most languages I can have a conditional like a `switch` block in a constructor to decide on what arguments to pass to the super constructor.
How to do that in Dart?
My use case is passing a map to my constructor, depending on what `map['type']` is, I insert a different `Widget` to the layout as an argument to the super constructor by using a switch block.

Comment: You can use the ternary if `cond ? expr : otherExpr`. If this is not the answer you are looking for, please make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter uses like React ternary operations. Those can be applied right in the constructor.

```
condition ? value is true : value is false
```

Here is a more detailed explaining: [Conditional Operator](https://codeburst.io/javascript-the-conditional-ternary-operator-explained-cac7218beeff)

You could also use a LayoutBuilder. If you are building a widget you can do something like this:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (var) {
        case conditionA:
            return widgetA;
        case conditionB:
            return widgetB;
    }
}
```

Comment: But I need a switch here

Comment: Do not use a layout builder for this, just a regular builder.  Layout builder is relatively expensive